# Very new to verilog. Can't assign values in a loop

Tags: verilog

I'm very new to verilog and not sure what data types to use. I'm trying to iterate over a binary number and xor each bit. I can do this manually, but I can't store it into a different reg.

```
module iterator(a, b);
    input [3:0] a;
    input [3:0] b;
    integer i = 0;
    reg [3:0] c = 4'b0000;

    always @ (a or b) begin
        $display("p = %b", p);
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i=i+1)
            c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
            $display("i = %d, a[i] = %b, b[i] = %b, a[i] ^ b[i] = %b", i, a[i], b[i], c[i]);
    end
endmodule

module Testbench;
    reg [3:0] a = 4'b1001;
    reg [3:0] b = 4'b0110;

    iterator it(a, b);
endmodule
```

Comment: If this code is going to be synthesized, remember that loops in HDLs will be unrolled and the logic will be duplicated for every loop iteration. They can take up a lot of space on your target hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Just to point out:

1: your display statement is misaligned. It is not inside the for loop. (This is not python thank god!) Use:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i=i+1)
begin
   c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
   $display("i = %d, a[i] = %b, b[i] = %b, a[i] ^ b[i] = %b", i, a[i], b[i], c[i]);
end
```

2: there is no variable 'p' which suggest this is not the code you used (syntax error).

3: Your code has no output. You EXOR bits but return no result as you have no output port.

4: initialising c to 4'b0000 is not always synthesize-sable. It is a bad habit and should be avoided unless it is strictly necessary. (Which is not here).

But all that goes away if you use toolic's code.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the code inside an always block to be executed, you need to make sure that the values of the variables in sensitivity list are changed. In your example you need a test bench to do so.

In your always block `a` and `b` are the signals which trigger execution of the code inside the block, if any of them changes.

```
always @ (a or b) begin
    $display("p = %b", p);
```

To do provide such a change you can do something like the following:

```
module Testbench;
    reg [3:0] a;
    reg [3:0] b;

    iterator it(a, b);

    initial begin
        a = 4'b1001;
        b = 4'b0110;
       #2
        a = 4'b0110;
        b = 4'b1111;
       #2 
      ...
    end
endmodule
```